# how to slice a array in tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, slice

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras

a = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

def helper(m):
    x = m[0]
    y = m[1]
    idx = tf.where(x>0.3)
    y = tf.gather(y, idx)
    return y
def helper_output_shape(input_shape):
    return (2,2,1)
x1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
x2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
r = keras.layers.Lambda(helper, output_shape=helper_output_shape)([x1,x2])

model = keras.Model([x1,x2],r)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.predict([a,b])
```

As the codes show, there are two arrays: scores and target. I want to slice a target array based on the scores. 
For example（as show in the codes above）:

```
a = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]) # scores array
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])           # target array

# I want to keep the value that has a higher score than 0.3 in b, and remove the rest. So the result should be array([4,5])
```

but got this error.
error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,1) into shape (5,2,1)
```

I tried to use the output_shape in Lambda to solve the issue mismatch of shapes between input and output but won't work. How to fix this problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as this particular error is concerned you could return like this.

```
def helper(m):
    x = m[0]
    y = m[1]
    idx = tf.where(x>0.3)
    y = tf.gather(y, idx)
    print( y.get_shape())  #This prints (?, 2, 1)
    return tf.constant([0,0,0,1,1],tf.float32)   #This can be coded generically.
```

This example return value solves the shape problem. We match the 5 in (5,2,1) which it is expecting. 5 is the number of the elements in the input.

Comment: I don't understand. If returning a constant, it makes all these meaningless. Isn't it?

Comment: No. I meant that any valid value that has as many number of elements as the input can be used. That was an example. This is specifically for this example and error.

Comment: I know why this error happened. I think it is because of the mismatch between the input shape and output shape. I want to know how to fix it. Actually, I want the output to be `array([4,5])` with a shape (2,1). Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: I or others can. Please update your question with this detail so that others can help too.